# nodejs pure websocket delivery status

Tags: node.js, networking, tcp, websocket

I am writing a chat for mobile devices using websocket plus nodejs (server proxies messages from one client to another) and met such a problem: if connection is not properly closed (plane mode, or cable unplugged), send function still success and no error occurs (error is always undefined):

```
  websocket.send(date.toISOString(), function ack(error) {
        if (error) {
           //Android push notification should be here
           log.error("Send error" + error);
        }
  });
```

Of course after some timeout (in implementation which I am using it is 15 minutes) connection is closed, if the cable will be plugged back I will receive all messages, but I am loosing all messages that were send between cable was unplugged (airplane mode was on) and timeout event if it finally occurs.

So the question is - if it is any way to find that message was delivered/undelivered, or get **all** undelivered messages when close event because of timeout occurs?
Or at least check if TCP socket is still opened? Because writing on system level on C/C++ it is very easy....

I used this websocket implementation: https://github.com/websockets/ws, the same result were with this one WebSocket-Node

Here is the snippet on github gist: https://gist.github.com/SKART1/b0635f07d1b5799880d7

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK The way you use socket it doesn't support callbacks. At least in socket.io implementation. Read more details [here](http://cjihrig.com/blog/how-to-use-websockets/)

The callback function you specified will never be called unless you were lucky to have an eventListener exactly for that timestamp.
The syntax would be either

```
client:
websocket.send('eventName', function callback(error, paramFromServer){});

server:
websocket.on('eventName', function handler(callback){
    try{
       do work here...
       callback(null, result);
    }
    catch(ex){
       callback(ex.message, null);
    } 
})
```

or (handle all messages with one handler including unnamed messages)

```
client:
websocket.send(data);

server:
websocket.onmessage = function allEventsHandler(data){
    process(data);
};
```

Note that in first scenario the callback will be called ONLY on successful return from server. The parameter will never be automatic. It should be supplied from server.

To solve dropped packets problems you might wish to put a handler for `onerror`.

```
websocket.onerror = function(event) {
  // handle error event
};
```

However, keep in mind the huge default timeout period for dropped packets.